# I am using Coordinator layout and Collapsing toolbar in my app and the toolbar is only half visible

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

this is my xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
android:id="@+id/road_coordinator_id"
android:background="@color/primary_light"

android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/primary_light"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/maintoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/viewpager_id"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/road"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainbackdrop"
        tools:context=".Fragments.road">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cameraicon"
    android:id="@+id/camera_road"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Location"
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_below="@+id/camera_road"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/gps_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/camera_road"
            android:id="@+id/road_gps_id"
            />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_loc_road"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/camera_road"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:hint="Location"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/road_landmark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_loc_road"
        android:hint="Landmark"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/road_desc"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/road_landmark"
        android:hint="Description"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/user_road"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/road_desc"
        android:hint="Reporter"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Phone number"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_road"
        android:id="@+id/phone_road_id"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonroad"
        android:background="@drawable/pressed"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_road"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/camera_road" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/btncancel"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonroad"
        android:background="@drawable/pressed"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/camera_road" />



</RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

So inside the collapsing toolbar layout i have a toolbar and its stuck at the top.There  should be a toolbar below which there is a view pager .
 I am not able to figure out why. If its a silly mistake forgive me. I am new to android.

[image: Road/Potholes is half stuck at the top]

My Activity xml file
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame_replace"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

</FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
I am replacing the frame layout with fragment. The toolbar in my activity is getting replaced by the fragment toolbar once the fragment is back pressed. I hope this helps explain my problem more clearly.

Comment: Finally understood the problem...I had not set the minimum height of the toolbar so it was showing...silly mistake from my side

Answer (score 0):

android:fitsSystemWindows="true" add this line in your root view.

Comment: I have added that too...but no use